# Analysis Continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity

I've come across the following question and don't have any idea where to start with it.. so any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Let  $ C^1([0,1])$ deonte the space of continuously differentiable functions on the interval [0,1] with the supremum norm inherited from C([0,1]).

Which of the following maps are continuous? Give a proof or counterexample:

1) $X_1: (C([0,1],||\cdot||_\infty) \rightarrow(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ given by $X_1f=\int^1_0f(t)\ dt$

2)$X_2: (C([0,1],||\cdot||_\infty) \rightarrow(C([0,1],||\cdot||_\infty)$ given by $(X_2f)(t)=\int^t_0f(s)\ ds.$

3$X_3: (C^1([0,1],||\cdot||_\infty) \rightarrow(C([0,1],||\cdot||_\infty)$ given by $(X_3f)(t)=f'(t).$

Please help me to try and understand what I need to do :)

Comment: Could you make the title more descriptive? Maybe like "Continuity of various functions under the sup norm" or something, so people know what the question is asking by the title alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$

Let $f\in C([0,1])$ and $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in C([0,1])$ with $\|f-f_n\|_\infty \underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

You want to prove that $\left|\int^1_0f(t)\ dt-\int^1_0f_n(t)\ dt\right|\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

$\left|\int^1_0f(t)\ dt-\int^1_0f_n(t)\ dt\right|=\left|\int^1_0(f(t)-f_n(t))\ dt\right|\le\int^1_0\left|f(t)-f_n(t)\right| dt \le \int^1_0\left\|f-f_n\right\|_\infty\ dt=\left\|f-f_n\right\|_\infty\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

---

$2)$

Let $f\in C([0,1])$ and $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in C([0,1])$ with $\|f-f_n\|_\infty \underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

You want to prove that $\left\|x\mapsto\int^x_0f(t)\ dt-\int^x_0f_n(t)\ dt\right\|_\infty\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

$\left\|x\mapsto\int^x_0f(t)\ dt-\int^x_0f_n(t)\ dt\right\|_\infty =\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\int^x_0f(t)\ dt-\int^x_0f_n(t)\ dt\right|=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\int^x_0(f(t)-f_n(t))\ dt\right|\le\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int^x_0\left|f(t)-f_n(t)\right|\ dt\le\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\int^x_0\left\|f-f_n\right\|_\infty\ dt=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}x\left\|f-f_n\right\|_\infty=\left\|f-f_n\right\|_\infty\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

---

$3)$

Take any bounded and Lipschitz continuous function $f\in C^1(\Bbb R)$. Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, we know that $f'$ is bounded.

Define $g_n(x)\in C^1([0,1])$ by $g_n(x)=\cfrac{f(nx)}{n}$

$g_n'(x)=\cfrac{nf'(nx)}{n}=f'(nx)$

$\|g_n\|_\infty = \sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|g_n(x)\right|=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|\cfrac{f(nx)}{n}\right|=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\cfrac{\left|f(nx)\right|}{n}=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,n]}\cfrac{\left|f(x)\right|}{n}=\cfrac{\sup\limits_{x\in[0,n]}\left|f(x)\right|}{n}=\cfrac{\|f\|_\infty}{n}\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$

$\|g_n'\|_\infty = \sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|g_n'(x)\right|=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}\left|f'(nx)\right|=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,n]}\left|f'(x)\right|$

So if we add to our requirements that $f|_{\Bbb R_+}\not = 0$, that is $\exists x_0\in \Bbb R_+, f(x_0)\not= 0$, we get $\|g_n'\|_\infty=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,n]}\left|f'(x)\right|\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\sup\limits_{x\in \Bbb R_+}\left|f'(x)\right|\ge |f(x_0)|>0$

If $X_3$ were continuous then $g_n \underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb 0 \Rightarrow g_n' \underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb 0'=\Bbb 0$ but we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|g_n'\|_\infty>0$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} g_n' \not = \Bbb 0$. Therefore, $X_3$ is not continous (because we can find such $f$, for example $\cos$).

Comment: Your explanations are great, thank you... I'm a little confused why there is the requirement in part 3 that $ \not = 0 $ ?

Comment: Well if $f=\Bbb 0$ then $\forall  n, g_n=\Bbb 0$ so $\forall n, g_n' =\Bbb 0$ so $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}X_3 ( g_n)=\Bbb 0=X_3(\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}g_n)$. Since we want a counterexample, we don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, note that if $\|f-g\|_\infty<\epsilon$ then 
$$\left|\int_0^1 f(t)dt-\int_0^1g(t)dt\right|\leq \int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|dt<\int_0^1\epsilon dt=\epsilon$$
and so the function is continuous. The argument for 2 is similar but more complicated, and I leave it to you. For 3, consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\cos(nx)$. This sequence converges to $0$ in the supremum norm, but the derivatives do not converge.

Answer (score 0):

To prove (1), you can show that for any $f\in C([0,1])$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|X_1f-X_1g|<\epsilon$ whenever $g\in C([0,1])$ with $\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty<\delta.$

To prove (2), you can show that for any $f\in C([0,1])$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\lVert X_2f-X_2g\rVert_\infty<\epsilon$ whenever $g\in C([0,1])$ with $\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty<\delta.$

To prove (3), you can show that for any $f\in C^1([0,1])$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\lVert X_3f-X_3g\rVert_\infty<\epsilon$ whenever $g\in C^1([0,1])$ with $\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty<\delta.$

In at least one of the cases, you'll need a counterexample. Try finding a sequence of $f_n$s that converges in the sup-norm, but such that the $X_jf_n$s don't converge.